# Problemas con Notificaciones cuando la app esta abierta

Tags: android, push, notificaciones

Buen dia, tengo un problema con las notificaciones de Firebase, y AndroidStudio y es que la notificacion, "cuando la app esta abierta y le doy click", no hace nada, solo me manda a la pantalla principal de login de la app.
si la aplicacion esta cerrada o en segundo plano al darle click si realiza la accion que en este caso es abrir una actividad y pasarle extras, pero si la app esta abierta y le doy click a la notificacion, esta no hace nada, quiero hacer que cuando la app este abierta y llegue la NOTIFICACION, haga lo mismo que cuando le doy click y la app esta cerrada

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage message) {
    super.onMessageReceived(message);
    String mensaje = message.getFrom();
    Log.e("tokenf", "msg"+mensaje);
    notiTitle=message.getData().get("Title");
    mayorOreo(message.getData().get("Title"), message.getData().get("Detalle"));
}

private void mayorOreo(String titulo, String detalle){
    Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+ "://" + getPackageName() +"/" + R.raw.song);

    String  id= "mensaje";
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder buldier = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,id);
    NotificationChannel nc = new NotificationChannel(id, "nuevo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
            .build();
    //personalizamos la notificacion
    nc.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
    nc.setShowBadge(true);
    nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);
    buldier.setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).
            setContentTitle(titulo).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
            setContentText(detalle).
            setSound(soundUri).
            setContentIntent(clickNoty())
            .setContentInfo("Nuevo");
    Random random = new Random();
    int notifyId = random.nextInt(9000);
    assert nm!=null;
    nm.notify(notifyId, buldier.build());


}

public PendingIntent clickNoty(){
    Intent iNoti = new Intent(this,DetalleAlerta.class);
    String part[] = notiTitle.split(": ");
    iNoti.putExtra("notiIncidenteId",part[1]);
    iNoti.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, iNoti,PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE| PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

}

Comment: Hay que poner comas en el texto, lo que dices es que cuando la app esta abierta, al abrir la notificación no hace nada?

Comment: eso entendí, @Jorgesys . Lo que quiere el user, es que, al pulsar la notificación, sí o sí te lleve a la Activity/view a la que espera llegar, no que no haga nada. (algo así como lo que hacen las notificaciones de whatsApp, supongo)

Comment: Si es correcto, cuando la app ya esta abierta y llega la notificacion, al darle click me deberia llevar a una actividad de "detalles"  (asi lo hace cuando esta cerrada o en segundo plano)
pero en este caso si tengo abierta la app y llega la notificacion, al darle click me manda a la pantalla principal del Login

Answer (score 0):

No encontre la solucion, pero me di cuenta de algo:
esto solo pasa en Api 33, que es android 13 en todas las demas versiones de Android la notificicion si abre correctamente al lanzarse el intent
y solo pasaba con una actividad en especifico de las 5 que tenia mi app, lo que hice fue mandar a una actividad antes al usuario y de ahi valido si el intent trae datos y lo mando a la actividad correspondiente, no es lo optimo pero al ser un cambio rapido de actividad, el usuario nunca distingue si abrio una actividad antes